# How to convert an infinite binary fraction into a decimal fraction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binary

I am asked to write the infinite binary fraction $0.(1011)$, where the $1011$ is the repeating part, as a $\frac pq$ fraction.

What are the steps to do this?

EDIT:

If $0.(1011)$ was in base 10, I could write it as $\frac {337}{3333}$... hmm how can this help?

EDIT EDIT: got it now :) it's $\frac {11}{15}$

Comment: How would you do it of $0.(1011)$ was in base 10?

Comment: That's not "how you would do it" in base 10. That's the answer in base 10.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  You can do the same as you do for converting a repeating decimal to a fraction.  As the repeat has four bits, multiply by $2^4$ and subtract the original.  All the repeating bits will disappear.  Can you see the link to the sum of a geometric series?

Answer (score 1):

A hint: Your $0.(1011)$ is short for
$$0+{1011_2\over 2^4}+{1011_2\over 2^8}+{1011_2\over 2^{12}}+{1011_2\over 2^{16}}+\ldots\quad.$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$(\cdots B_1B_0.b_0b_1\cdots)_r=\cdots r^1\cdot B_1+r^0\cdot B_0+b_0\cdot r^{-1}+b_1\cdot r^{-2}\cdots$$